# Organizing elements in a span tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a span element `R` and elements `space, chk, and text` which hold newline character, a checkbox element, and a text node, respectively.

Here is the javascript I use to attach the elements:

```
     R.appendChild(space);
     R.appendChild(chk);
     R.appendChild(txt);
```

and HTML for the span:

```
Selected   Address    <span style="position:absolute: top:100px; right:700px;"id="results">&nbsp;</span>
```

What would be an effective way to organize these elements so that they are printed in row/column forum on the page? Like this:

```
Selected     Address

checkbox     64-21 broad street
checkbox     58-99 narrow street
```

I am dynamically generating these elements so it would have to be written in javascript and be automated. On a side note, I'm also having trouble positioning the span on the page. Changing the "position" in the style attribute seems to have no effect on it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Organize your HTML into rows and use a stylesheet  to position the elements. JavaScript seems like it would be overkill here.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Right now it seems like you're asking how to create a table, or at least a tabular display. The answer is: Use a `table`, or elements with fixed widths defined by CSS. Also, you've said `space` contains a newline character. If so, `R.appendChild(space);` should be throwing an error, as `appendChild` requires you pass it a `Node`.

Comment: The space variable actually contains a node which holds "br" not the character on it's own. I guess a table is what I'm looking for, I just want to know how to present the generated data neatly. If I knew how to set equal space between each column, I could just print the elements with the space inbetween and then call a newline character at the end of each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like tabular data, so use an HTML table: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp

Answer (score 1):

Small question about the span element...

In the span's `style` attribute, is that second colon (between "absolute" and "top") a typo?  Looks like it should be a semi-colon.

Dunno whether the span'll still be relevant if you go with an HTML table structure (as others've already suggested), but...  :-)